# Java: can't use Map.Entry to iterate over a Map?

Tags: java

Every Java Map iteration example I've seen recommends this paradigm:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : hashMap.entrySet()) {
   String key = item.getKey();
   String value = item.getValue();
}
```

However, when I attempt to do this I get a warning from my compiler:

```
Incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>
```

Here's my code - the only wrinkle I see is that I'm iterating over an array of Map objects, and then iterating over the elements of the individual Map:

```
result = getArrayOfMaps();
// Force to List LinkedHashMap
List<LinkedHashMap> result2 = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>();
for (Map m : result) {
  LinkedHashMap<String, Object> n = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : m.entrySet()) {
     n.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
  }
  result2.add(n);
}
```

Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Comment: I think you have a typo, it should be `n.entrySet()` instead of `m.entrySet()`

Comment: I think either you need to use `n.entrySet()` or else you can you please share what is type of `result`

Comment: Type of `m` is ambiguous here `for(Map m : result){`. It assumes `Map<Object>`. You need to supply known type to it like `for(Map<String, Object> m : result){`. It might come from `result` itself

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx is right. `Map m` is a raw type, and therefore everything coming from it uses raw types. Its `entrySet()` method doesn't return a `Set<Map.Entry<...>>` but a `Set` - again raw types. You may need to add some (unchecked) casts in some places to make this work.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings and you will be notified of mistakes like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are using raw types: a `List<LinkedHashMap>` instead of a `List<LinkedHashMap<Something, SomethingElse>>`.  As a result, the `entrySet` is just a `Set` instead of a `Set<Map.Entry<Something, SomethingElse>>`. Don't do that.